# iTunesConnect app has one or more issues - Non-public API usage

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I received the below email shortly after I submit my app to the AppStore from XCode Organizer. My app contains the framework in this GitHub (https://github.com/wujianguo/iOSAppsInfo), I use it to create shortcuts to the rest of the users installed applications, and ONLY for that purpose. 
Is there a different way of getting a list of all installed apps so I can create shortcuts or will all methods be instantly rejected as below?

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery "shortcut-app". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Non-public API usage:

The app references non-public selectors in Xxxx xxxx: _applicationIconImageForBundleIdentifier:format:scale:, allInstalledApplications, appTags, applicationProxyForIdentifier:, localizedShortName, openApplicationWithBundleID:

If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed.

If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nine-digit Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information page.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Comment: You can't use this library in app that will be submitted to the AppStore. It uses private methods which are not allowed and there for your app got rejected.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks, in my previous app version I had manually written out a list of possible apps, so this made it a lot easier instead of users constantly requesting apps to be added to the supported list. Is there a simpler way or alternative??

Comment: No, you will have to add the apps to the support list before compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library uses private API which you cannot use especially when you submit the app to apple, as they will reject it like this.

I am not aware of another way to get installed apps, but in order for apple to accept uploading the app, you must stop using this library, specially this method.